# Axios query paramaters?

Tags: typescript, axios

when using postman I just enter query paramaters but in axios I am unable to do. I have to use string addition. is this bad?

```
 const url = "https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?pageNumber="+data.pageNumber+"&pageSize="+data.pageSize+"&q="+data.q+"&autoCorrect=true"
          const result = await axios.default.get(url,headers)
          const values = result.data.value
          for (const value of values) {
              const imageURL = value.url as string
              res.images.push(imageURL)
          }
         
          response.send(res)
```

thanks. I find axios to be really hard to use... it has 13m downloads maybe im using a hammer when all I need is a tap. Should I switch to lighter weight http service like unirest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to axios.get() is the Axios options: it will serialize options.params and add it to the query string. Try the following:

```
const res = await axios.get('https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI', { params: {pageNumber:data.pageNumber,pageSize:data.pageSize,q:data.q,autoCorrect:true},headers);
```

Comment: where do i put my headers that contains apikey etc?

Comment: updated the answer. 2nd parameter is option which accepts object.  like query key, headers key can be passed to it.

Comment: I am using typescript version of axios, cannot pass thrid params, expects only 2 D:

Comment: nvm solved it, just put everything in that one param.